# reference.addValueEventListener doesn't trigger

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with the `valueEventListener` in Android Studio using Firebase. My listener doesn't trigger, but my program is still launching and it crashes when I try to get my `userList`.

I want to get all my users in `userList` so I can load some data on my screen.

Please help me.

Here's my code :

```
        //init list
        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        //fill list
        //get current users
        final FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        //get path
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        //get all data
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                userList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    System.out.println(user);

                    //get all users except current
                    if (!user.getUid().equals(fUser.getUid())){
                        userList.add(user);
                    }
                    else{
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });

        //show a random user
        final Random random = new Random();
        System.out.println("size : " + userList.size());
        int random1 = random.nextInt(userList.size());

        User foundUser = userList.get(random1);
        userName.setText(foundUser.getName().trim());
        userTitle.setText(foundUser.getUid().trim());
        String pic = foundUser.getPic();
        try{
            //if good set image
            Picasso.get().load(pic).into(userImage);
        }catch (Exception e){
            //if not set default
            Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_add_image).into(userImage);
        }
        userList.remove(random1);
```

Comment: [because it isn't synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: include your full class/code and error log with your question.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: There is no error or log in the code. Because I think that my program still run through my function but don't let time to get all the data collected. I think I need a way to make the program wait for my data to be collected.

Comment: I assume you're looking for me here ?

Comment: I tried to make it synchronous but I didn't achieve it